# Can Maya 3D animations Embedded in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, maya

I am new to wpf. I have created a 3D animation in Maya Auto Desk. SO can i Embed it in WPF . is it possible ? Please help ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible by any stretch. But you could certainly render your animation into a video through Maya and then embed that in WPF through the `WebBrowser` control.

Comment: thankz il give it a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an older open source project to create a DirectX control for use in WPF at http://sharpdxwpf.codeplex.com/   However you'd need to convert the maya file to .x format for directX -- there used to be an exporter in the DirectX SDK but I don't know if it's been maintained.

This project offers a 3D component for wpf and also includes links to other 3d-wpf format: http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/  A quick look suggests it might not support animation right now (OBJ, for example, is not an animated format) but maybe the links will help.